# SSIS: Conditional Split result to variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have condition where I need to feed conditional split result based on condition (will be just one int value) to variable. Can some one help how to do this?

My actual package (Data flow):

`XML Source` --> `Conditional split` *(based on condition) 2 outputs..one result based on condition (will be just one int value)*  need to pass it on to variable. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure SSIS way - consume your dataflow into a [Recordset Destination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879316.aspx) and then iterate through it with ForEach Loop, assigning value to the desired variable.

Comment: I believe no need to iterate through each as my conditional split always gives single result. My point here being fresher to SSIS I am not aware how to assign the conditional split result to variable.

Comment: @narendragc, you can assign your 0-th column value to your desired variable in ForEach Loop definition, and leave Loop sequence empty. Thus, loop will set the variable, with the only drawback - the variable will store the last value from rows collection. If you will have just one row - it does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a script component to achieve this:

- Create a script component (*Choose it's type as Destination*)

[image]

- Double click on script component and Choose your Variable as a `ReadWrite` Variable. (*in my example the variable is named **Result***

[image]

- Inside the script window write the following code

  ```
  Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

      If Not Row.inColumn_IsNull Then
          Variables.Result = Row.inColumn
      End If

  End Sub
  ```

*Side Note: Variable value does not change before `dataflowtask` execution is finish, to use the new value you have to continue your work in another `dataflowtask`*

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways to realize this.

First: Do it with a C# script component, this is the easiest way.
Just put a script component behind your conditional split, select your variable as "ReadWrite", then set it like that in the code:

```
Dts.Variables["yourvariable"].Value = Input0Buffer.Yourcolumn
```

I don't have access to SSIS right now, so I can't give you the exact code, but this should get you started.

Second: Write to a table and read it back with Execute SQL task. I don't really like this way ;-)